# Distribute a month in weeks with start and end dates array

Tags: php, date, time

I'm making a function that would break current month into an array of weeks, each week with its starting and ending date. For example the current month is September, so this is what I expect my function to return:

```
$week_arr[1]['start'] = '1-09-2014';
$week_arr[1]['end'] = '7-09-2014';
$week_arr[2]['start'] = '8-09-2014';
$week_arr[2]['end'] = '14-09-2014';
/*
.
.
.
*/
$week_arr[5]['start'] = '29-09-2014';
$week_arr[5]['end'] = '30-09-2014';
```

I understand that only non-leap February will have 4 weeks. 
This is what I have so far

```
$no_of_days_in_month = date("t");
$no_of_weeks = (ceil(intval($no_of_days_in_month)/7));

$week_inc = 0;
$curr_month_year = date("m-Y");

$week_arr = array();
for($i = 1; $i <= $no_of_weeks; $i++){
    $week_arr[$i]['start'] = ($week_inc+1)."-".$curr_month_year;
    $week_arr[$i]['end'] = ($week_inc+7)."-".$curr_month_year;
    $week_inc += 7;
}
var_dump($week_arr);
```

It works almost correctly, except I want it to stop on the last day of the month in the last week.
Above code has a problem with the `5th` index of the week. It results

```
  $week_arr[5]['start'] = '29-09-2014'
  $week_arr[5]['end'] = '35-09-2014'
```

How to fix that?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a check to the start of your `for` loop to stop processing if the end date is greater than the number of days in the month:

```
if($week_inc + 7 > $no_of_days_in_month)
    break;
```

[Output](https://eval.in/186860)

Or if you still want the partial week at the end, you could use a similar check to define what the last day should be:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= $no_of_weeks; $i++){
    if($week_inc + 7 > $no_of_days_in_month)
        $day = $no_of_days_in_month;
    else
        $day = $week_inc + 7;

    $week_arr[$i]['start'] = ($week_inc+1)."-".$curr_month_year;
    $week_arr[$i]['end'] = $day."-".$curr_month_year;
    $week_inc += 7;
}
```

[You'll then get](https://eval.in/186862) a partial week at the end:

```
[5] => Array
    (
        [start] => 29-09-2014
        [end] => 30-09-2014
    )
```

Comment: Yes. I was about to comment that an `else` might be required here. Let me test the code with hard-coded months like February and some other month with 31 days but it seems like the function would work just fine. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use a `DatePeriod` class for this one too. Example:

```
$begin = new DateTime('first day of ' . date('Y-m-d'));
$end = new DateTime('last day of ' . date('Y-m-d'));
$interval = new DateInterval('P1W');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

$dates = array();
foreach($daterange as $key => $date) {

    $check = ($date->format('W') != $end->modify('last day of this month')->format('W')) ? '+6 days' : 'last day of this week';
    $dates[$key+1] = array(
        'start' => $date->format('Y-m-d'),
        'end' => $date->modify($check)->format('Y-m-d'),
    );
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($dates);
```

Should yield this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2014-09-01
            [end] => 2014-09-07
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2014-09-08
            [end] => 2014-09-14
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2014-09-15
            [end] => 2014-09-21
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2014-09-22
            [end] => 2014-09-28
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2014-09-29
            [end] => 2014-09-30
        )

)
```